# Clang Installation

Tags: linux, download, installation, clang, llvm

I am trying to use Clang.

First, I downloaded the first two source files (LLVM source code + Clang source code) from [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.8.1), under section "download llvm 3.8.1".

Then, I extracted them, and renamed the obtained extracted directories to llvm and clang (respectively). Then, I put the clang directory inside llvm/tools.

Finally, I followed the instuctions [here](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html), under the section "building Clang and working with the code", in the subsection "on Unix-like systems".

BTW, the reason why I renamed the directories to clang and llvm as in these insturctions these are the names of the directories, so I guess I should rename them.

And in step 9 ("try it out"), when I typed "clang --help", I got the message:

"The program 'clang' can be found in the following packages:

- clang 3.3
- clang 3.4
- clang 3.5

Try sudo apt-get install < selected package >"

This means that the installation failed.
Why? What else should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems either the build failed before, but you should have noticed, or you didn't set your PATH appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The newly built `clang` will be in the `bin` directory of the build directory and this build directory is the location where you executed the command:

```
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" <path_to_the_sources>
```

To run this clang, you will need to add the path to it:

```
$ <path_to>/bin/clang
```

Or you can -- as the instructions you referred to suggest -- add the full path to the clang to your PATH variable.

If your current directory is where `clang` is located, then you still need to add the current directory to it by using `./`:

```
$ ./clang
```

This is not specific to clang by the way. If you type the name of any executable without a path:

```
$ <name_of_executable>
```

then the command-line interpreter will look for that executable in all the directories in the $PATH variable.

You can look at the list of these directories by entering

```
$ echo $PATH
```

And you will see something like

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

The command line interpreter will iterate through the list and will start the executable **only** if it's found in one of these directories.

(On Windows, the command line interpreter will also look in the current directory; this is why entering the name of the program by itself works if it is located in the current directory)

You can see where a program that can be executed without specifying the path is located by using the `which` command:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

and to pay our dues to the recursive tradition of Unix:

```
$ which which
/usr/bin/which
```